# Using style from Cloudmade on Leaflet.js maps

Tags: javascript, openstreetmap, leaflet, cloudmade

I'm using Leaflet for my web project. For the map tile, I'm using Cloudmade images.

```
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/{key}/22677/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        styleId: 123544,
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; 2011 OpenStreetMap contributors, Imagery &copy; 2012 CloudMade',
        key: 'XXXXXXXX'
    }).addTo(map);
```

I've tried to put the style to this map but the style doesn't work. I just want to put blue on river and sea.

Thank you.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the code, but I get a gray/empty map with Leaflets example code and a free API key aswell. Looks like Cloudmade switched its payment model ([read here](http://notes.ericjiang.com/posts/741)), so if you aren't a paying customer you are out of luck :( -- **Edit:** Sorry, that says May 1st, this is not the issue here

Comment: Okay so I tried your exact code and it shows up correctly, make sure you run it from the domain you have specified in your Cloudmade API key settings

Comment: http://apb.directionsmag.com/entry/cloudmade-ends-smaller-service-plans-offers-only-enterprise-level-serv/387341

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use cloudmade on one of my website, this is how i use their tiles :

```
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/{your_key}/{style_id}/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; 2011 OpenStreetMap contributors, Imagery &copy; 2012 CloudMade'
}).addTo(map);
```

Key and style are directly in the url, you might want to use the basic cloudmade style, id is `1`.

And yes, cloudmade is turning off their service for small users, but it's not effective now, may 1st so your map should work.